# generate pdf of google map in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

i'm trying to generate pdf of google map, which is generated by gm4r plugin using wicked_pdf, unfortunately map is not genereted in the pdf.
Need some help on this
rails v= 2.3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hai my problem using solved using static gmap gem . now i can able to generate the pdf of the map. thank